# Allow non-root application modify read-only file in /etc

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to have an almost idiotproof configurator for network and some other stuff for embedded device running on linux. Application is saving to /etc/network/interfaces without problem when run by root, but returns "segmentation fault" when run by standard user. strace returned:

> open("/etc/network/interfaces", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
>   --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0} ---

How can I allow it to be launched by anyone and write to /etc/network/interfaces ?

Code for saving to file:

```
            FILE *saveFile;
            saveFile = fopen("/etc/network/interfaces","w");
            // loopback
            fprintf(saveFile, "auto lo \niface lo inet loopback\n\n");
            // eth0
            fprintf(saveFile, "auto eth0\niface eth0 inet static\n\taddress %s\n\tnetmask %s\n\tgateway %s\n",
                    address,netmask,gateway);
            fclose(saveFile);
```

Comment: maybe off topic: why don;t you check for success of `fopen()` first?

Comment: `chmod a+w /etc/network/interfaces`, or make the program suid root

Comment: Just require root access. Non-root users should not be allowed to modify interface information.

Comment: Why do you want this application to be used by anybody? `/etc/network/interfaces/' is a system file and modifying it is an administrative operation that should be done as root.

Comment: Long story's short version: I need user to be able to move device freely between networks, but I don't want to give root to user.

Comment: Have them send you an e-mail and then you do it.

Comment: as an option set SUID bit for your application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this :

- install sudo
- create a new user
- Give sudo permission for the new user only on your program.

This way, when people will try to execute any command other than your program,it will be refused.

Now, your program will run with sudo rigth, so make sure that your program cannot be modified or replaced by another program (like chmod 700 and chown root) and make sure your program will not mess /etc/network/interface

Comment: it seems to be working, now I'll just have to handle security issues and tests of returns like Serge Ballesta advised. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Yes, because if someone someday find a way to mess the system with your program, you may find yourself in big trouble. Clearly, check and double check user input, check every function that can be fail (your SIGSEV give me cold sweat).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I allow it to be launched by anyone and write to /etc/network/interfaces ?

Mmmmm... By giving write permissions to anyone on /etc/network/interfaces ?

Comment: Are you sure that it is really a good advice? Would you do that on your own machine? **I** certainly won't!

Comment: Well I'm not giving advice here, just answering the question literally.

Answer (score 1):

After your comment, your requirement is to allow a non root user to do a particular administrative tasks that would require root priviledge. The traditional way would be to make the program owned by root and setuid. This is now a throwned upon way, because a setuid program (su or sudo are) should be thoroughly scrutinized for any potential security problem: a buffer overflow or other would allow execution of arbitrary code **as root**.

For your example, if it is a simple program, it could make sense, but at least the return value of every operation (`fopen` and `fwrite` here) should be tested!

The recommended way for that will now be to use `sudo` and set specific entries in the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow any user (or a specific list of groups and/or users) to execute that specific command as root. To achieve almost the same that a setuid command but prompt the user for his/her password to notice him/her of an administrative task:

```
ALL local_host_name = (root) /full/path/to/command
```

But the sudoers syntax allow much finer grained authorizations.

(Beware: you still have to twice control your code)